# how to debug an event that is not fired even if its assigend

Tags: delphi, debugging, events, delphi-2009

I'm looking for the code that checks if the event is assigned, and if so, fires it.

What code manage the events?

Suggestions?

I have a custom component, that is connected to `AdoQuery`, that hold `TField`. My component, does not fire the `OnSetText` of the `TField`, while other components allow the fire of the `OnSetText` even. im trying to locate the reason.

ok, here is source code:

```
procedure TForm1.ADOQuery1MydateSetText(Sender: TField; const Text: string);
var
  Garbage:TDateTime;
begin
  if TryStrToDate(text,Garbage) then
    Sender.AsString := Text
  else ShowMessage('so now what?');
end;
```

How to trace the code that makes the call to this code, inside Delphi?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically an event handler will be declared with a property declared like this:

```
property OnMyEvent: TMyEvent read FOnMyEvent write FOnMyEvent;
```

So, in order to fire it the code will execute `FOnMyEvent` and so you need to search the component's source code for references to `FOnMyEvent` or possibly `OnMyEvent`. Usually you will find something like this:

```
procedure TMyComponent.DoMyEvent;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnMyEvent) then
    FOnMyEvent(Self);
end;
```

Finally, you need to look for the places where `DoMyEvent` is called.

---

As a worked example, we can use the `OnSetText` event of `TField`. This is declared like this:

```
property OnSetText: TFieldSetTextEvent read FOnSetText write FOnSetText;
```

That's the only reference to `OnSetText`. So we look for `FOnSetText` which leads to this:

```
procedure TField.SetEditText(const Value: string);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnSetText) then FOnSetText(Self, Value) else SetText(Value);
end;
```

Now, `SetEditText` is a private method, so we don't need to look outside the unit in which it is declared. And the only place it is used is as the property setter for `TField.Text`:

```
property Text: string read GetEditText write SetEditText;
```

Then you could continue and look for the places where that property is assigned to, but there will be a lot of places where that happens. So, if you want to debug all this you simply need to enable Debug DCUs and set a breakpoint inside `TField.SetEditText`. You may wish to make the break point condition on the content of `Value` if your find that the break point fires too often.